# web server show pdf in UIWebView but didFailLoadWithError in iOS run with xcode 6

Tags: ios

PDF file error with run in xcode 6.0
It's not work ......

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its going to encode .. try it. Within url 'record id_2_1_1410848039.pdf' in between record and id space count.

```
  UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        webView.delegate = self;
 NSString *getURL = @"http://google.com/images/item_attachment/282/record id_2_1_1410848039.pdf";
        NSString *encodedString=[getURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
        webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```